# Display array of base64 image data as images

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am outputting a RadListView of items each of which has an image in base64 format and I having trouble displaying them.

In the component loop I have

```
let base64ImageSource = new ImageSource;
base64ImageSource = fromBase64(returned_expenses[i].receipt_data);
```

and in the template I have

```
<Image row="0" col="1" [src]="base64ImageSource" horizontalAlignment="right" width="100" height="100"  stretch="none"></Image>
```

and there is no image.

I have seen the following code

```
this.imageSource = new ImageSource();
var loadedBase64 = this.imageSource.loadFromBase64(MY_BASE_64_STRING_PREVIOUSLY_SAVED);
console.log(loadedBase64);
if (loadedBase64) {
  let photo = <Image>this.photoImage.nativeElement;
  photo.imageSource = this.imageSource;
  this.photo = photo;
}
```

but I do not know what to make of the line

```
let photo = <Image>this.photoImage.nativeElement;
```

ie. what photoImage is declared as?

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 2):

In your sample code `photoImage` could be a reference to an element, may be using [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

**HTML**

```
....
<Image #photoImage></Image>
...
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild("photoImage") photoImage: ElementRef;
```